# Can I go Schengen to Schengen via non-Schengen airport with a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen

I have a single-entry Schengen visa on my Indian passport. The visa is for visiting Finland. I have bought round trip tickets to Venice from Helsinki within the validity period of my Schengen visa. However, the flights are operated by Turkish Airlines and while going to Venice and returning from Venice to Helsinki, I have a stop-over at Istanbul.

Am I allowed to re-enter Helsinki on my single-entry Schengen visa?

Answer (score 4):

When you leave Finland on a flight to Istanbul you will get the stamp that you have left the Schengen area.
When you next arrive into the Schengen area, in Venice, you will be told you can not enter the area as you have used the one visit allowed.

More likely is that you are not allowed to enter the plane in Istanbul, as you will not have a valid visa for your arrival country.

Best re-book your flight to one that is direct, as you will not be allowed back into the Schengen Zone. Direct flight will be acceptable as would be surface travel as long as you stay within the Schengen zone (but that is a very long travel for this combination of countries.)
Or just forget the side step to Venice as it will likely not be worth to lose your visa for Finland over.